# Disabling a web service inbound gateway

Tags: web-services, spring-integration

I would like to be disable a web service inbound-gateway based on a database flag.

I have achieved this with other inbound adapters (e.g. file) by setting the auto-start attribute based on a SPEL expression which gets the database value.

Any advice on a good way to achieve this? I do not see an auto-start attribute on the ws:inbound-gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like it is a bug there around `Lifecycle` and in case of stopped state we should return to the client something like `HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`.

Please, raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) ticket on the matter and we will take care about that soon.
I see that `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` has similar problem, even if `auto-startup` is exposed there.

As a workaround I see something like `ChannelInterceptor` on the `request-channel` for you `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>`, which checks some variable and throws some exception (`NoEndpointFoundException` ?) from the `preSend()` implementation to notify WS client that the service isn't available.